# Reinstalling the iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, operating-systems, reinstall

After using my iPhone for over a year, I now have 7 pages of applications and the phone has started to become old and slow. Coming from the windows-world, I suspect that a clean install will help a bit. Maybe not as much as it helps for a windows-pc, but by getting rid of all those applications and having a clean install which is not updated from 2.0 to 2.1 to 2.whatever to 3.0 might help a bit.

So how do I do this in the simplest way possible? And don´t tell me to manually remove all apps, I want a clean install...

I am using a Mac (yeah, the iPhone made me realise that all those fanboys actually had a pretty good point, so I switched :P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to iTunes with your phone plugged in, you should see the phone in there.

If you do a restore, it will wipe it and reinstall the operating system.

When it is finished restoring you will have the option to resync data or configure a new phone.

What you do then is up to you, but, you will lose all your SMSs if you set up a new phone, but should be able to sync all contacts and other things again.

If you decide to restore the backup, it will copy all the data and settings you had before.

Here is a [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414)

Answer (score 1):

> And don´t tell me to manually remove
>   all apps, I want a clean install...

...but surely, even if you do a clean install, you'll get all those apps back the first time you sync?  To avoid that, you'll have to unselect them in iTunes.  And if you're going to do that (which will only take a few minutes at most), you may as well try it *before* reformatting your iPhone.